# What do scriptures say about eating unknown vegetables?

Tags: food

I understood from Manusmriti 5.5 that following veggies are to be avoided

> Garlic, leeks and onions, mushrooms and all that proceeds from impure things, are unfit to re eaten by twice-born men.—(5).

But what about vegetables that were introduced to India in recent past - e.g. Potatoes

When it comes to unknown animals or birds, the scriptures make it abundantly clear that they are to be avoided - Manusmriti 5.17

> He shall not eat solitary animals, nor **unknown** beasts and birds, even though indicated among those fit to be eaten; nor any five-nailed animals.—(17).

But looking for pointers on vegetables and fruits not native to Bharata.

Comment: "I understood from Manusmriti 5.5 that following veggies are to be avoided" are you a twice-born man? There is a discussion about this verse because some gurus say the manus smriti is only for a particular yuga.

Comment: I don't know which guru says that and for the purpose of getting an answer assume I am twice born.